# MySQL - how to check which items in an arbitrary list (~1,000 items) are in a table?

Tags: mysql

Here's my problem...

I need to be able to check which items in a list of about 1,000 items (the *needles*) are in a fairly large table containing about ~500,000 rows (the *haystack*).

My question is, what's the best/fastest/most efficient way to do this?

I know that I can create a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT id FROM haystack WHERE id IN (ID1, ID2, ID3, ..., IDn)
```

(assuming `ID1, ID2, ID3, ..., IDn` are the the needles.)

However, I'm not sure how performant or wise that is if the needles list contains 1,000+ items.

I also know that, if my needles list was in a table of it's own, I could `join` that table to the haystack table. However, the needles list ***isn't*** already in a table.

So - I guess another possible option is to put those 1,000 items into a temporary table and then join that to the haystack table. If that's the best option - then what's the best way to quickly load 1,000 items into a temporary table? (E.g., 1,000 individual `INSERT` statements? Insert all rows in a single `INSERT` statment? Is there a limit on how long an `INSERT` statement can be?)

A third possible option - write the *needles* list to a text file, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load that into a (temporary) table, then join the temp table to the *haystack* table. But, wow... that seems like a lot of overhead.

Is there another, better option?

For what it's worth, the context of this is PHP, and I'm getting the *needles* list from a JSON web-service response, and using MySQLi for the database interaction.

Comment: I would say creating and inserting a table would be much slower than dynamically creating the query, so go with the long `SELECT ... IN` statement, as long as your list is not too long. For max query length check the max_allowed_packet variable : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: Appropriately indexed, a JOIN will possibly be faster

Comment: @Strawberry there would be a lot of overhead for ensuring simultaneous connections don't overlap, and for the disk I/O to commit the results to disk/remove them after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this benchmark](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/), it is faster in your case to use a temporary table and the `JOIN` method.

I am not sure though that's not a premature optimisation. You should perform your own benchmark and determine if the added complexity deserves the effort. I would recommend going with the simple `IN` method and only start to optimise when you detect a performance issue.

Just remember that according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the `max_allowed_packet` value.

Comment: @avudenie - thanks for your response and the link. I expected that a join would be faster than `SELECT...IN`, but I've still got to get my 1,000 needles into the temp table first. So it sounds like the `SELECT` might be better, overall.

Comment: @mattstuehler: the `INSERT` occurs on each iteration of the benchmark, notice the `TRUNCATE TABLE t_param;` and the following  `INSERT INTO t_param (param) VALUES`. Even so, I expect the difference in your case to be almost insignificant.

Comment: @avudenie - thanks too for the correction. Really great link, and a great answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query `SELECT id FROM haystack WHERE id IN (ID1, ID2, ID3, ..., IDn)` would be fine. I have a very similar use case where I have millions of "needles" and I pass them to the IN clause in blocks of 10,000 via PDO with no issues.

I would add that the column you are checking should be indexed. In my case it is the primary key of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If the needles are going to be used to query the `haystack` frequently, you absolutely want to create a new table. For this example, I'm going to assume that the needles are `int` values and will label them as `id` in the table `needle`.

First, you need to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE needle (
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Next, you need to insert the values

```
INSERT INTO needle (id)
VALUES (ID1),
    (ID2),
    ...,
    (IDn)
```

Now, you can query `haystack` using a join.

```
SELECT h.id
FROM haystack h
JOIN needle n
ON h.id = n.id
```

If this is an infrequent query and the number of needles won't grow beyond the 1,000, using the IN clause won't hurt your performance greatly.